# Swift 3 - Fetch All Photos From Library

Tags: ios, swift, image, phfetchoptions

I've tried to fetch photos from the library. It works, but I just got 3 photos from 9 photos from the library. Here's my code:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
    let userAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType.album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.any, options: options)

    let userPhotos = PHAsset.fetchKeyAssets(in: userAlbums.firstObject!, options: nil)
    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    userPhotos?.enumerateObjects({ (object: AnyObject!, count: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer) in
        if object is PHAsset {
            let obj:PHAsset = object as! PHAsset

            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
            fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.isSynchronous = true

            imageManager.requestImage(for: obj, targetSize: CGSize(width: obj.pixelWidth, height: obj.pixelHeight), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { img, info in

                self.images.append(img!)
            })
        }
    })
```

When I tried `images.count`, it said 3. Can anyone help me to find my mistake and get all photos? Big thanks!

Comment: try using DKImagepickercontrolller a 3rd party API

Comment: you need to ensure first that you are authorized to access photos.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this,

first import photos

```
import Photos
```

then declare Array for store photo before viewDidLoad()

```
var allPhotos : PHFetchResult<PHAsset>? = nil
```

Now write code for fetch photo in viewDidLoad()

```
    /// Load Photos
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("Good to proceed")
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            self.allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("Not allowed")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined yet")
        }
    }
```

Now write this code for display image from Array

```
/// Display Photo
let asset = allPhotos?.object(at: indexPath.row)
self.imageview.fetchImage(asset: asset!, contentMode: .aspectFit, targetSize: self.imageview.frame.size) 


// Or Display image in Collection View cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectPhotoCell

    let asset = allPhotos?.object(at: indexPath.row)
    cell.imgPicture.fetchImage(asset: asset!, contentMode: .aspectFit, targetSize: cell.imgPicture.frame.size)

    return cell
}

extension UIImageView{
 func fetchImage(asset: PHAsset, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, targetSize: CGSize) {
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: contentMode, options: options) { image, _ in
        guard let image = image else { return }
        switch contentMode {
        case .aspectFill:
            self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        case .aspectFit:
            self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        }
        self.image = image
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: what is `self.imageview` ??

Comment: self.imageview is a your imageView where you need to display image, like as a profile pic, in tableview listing

Comment: You want to display in collection view right ? then you have a imageView in collection view's cell right?

Comment: wiil this code able to work for iCloud images  also?

Comment: This works perfectly fine but when I need to fetch the original size of the image waiting time takes too long. Do you have any suggestion for fetching fast and the original size of image

Comment: @SapanaRanipa
self.allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
-->
The return result is nil, can you help me?

Comment: @trumsuhu, You added photo library access permission into info.plist file ?

Comment: @SapanaRanipa Sorry, my mistake, it was loaded successful, thanks you so much! But now, i have another problem, when i load all photos from library (about 3000 photos), it will take a long time. Any suggestion? Thank again!

Comment: @trumsuhu, If it is taking too much time then you can add loading.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5 - Update**

First import Photos

```
Import Photos
```

Create a variable to hold all the images

```
var images = [UIImage]()
```

Main function to grab the assets and request image from asset

```
fileprivate func getPhotos() {

    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    // .highQualityFormat will return better quality photos
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    let results: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    if results.count > 0 {
        for i in 0..<results.count {
            let asset = results.object(at: i)
            let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700)
            manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                if let image = image {
                    self.images.append(image)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("error asset to image")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("no photos to display")
    }

}
```

Comment: adding explanation to your answer will be helpful

Comment: Works perfectly, but after fetching 3400 image from my library, app crashes because of this error: "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" . How can I handle memory warning?

Answer (score 1):

Check first in info.plist that your app is authorized to access photos from library. than Use the below code to access all photos:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("You Are Authrized To Access")
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
            print("Found number of:  \(allPhotos.count) images")
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("Not allowed")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined yet")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @cathrinnatalia Your question is about how to fetch the photos from library. Please don't expand your question.

Comment: extend the scope of allPhotos variable by taking it on top and within in the class than count from it and use it in collectionview. but this method should be in viewDidLoad.